# Mongodb replication fails after rebooting of the system

Tags: mongodb

As I have configured mongodb replication with 4 replica sets which was working fine before reboot of the system and after rebooting of the system its failing  to run replset  although mongod is running.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Off-topic, to be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com Voted to close here.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.